# Applying nested lapply functions

Tags: r, lapply

I created the following function with the intention of applying two iterations of lapply.

'x' here will be a list of 10 dataframes that each have the first column as the response variable.

first, i'm applying lapply to run an 'lm' on these dataframes by passing the list that holds them, and specifying first column as the response and running lm on all variables in the respective dataframe.

I then wish to create a column in each dataframe that would contain the fitted values once the 'lm' has been applied.

```
  runit<-function(x){
     {lapply(x,function(data){lm(reformulate(termlabels=".",
      response=names(data)[1]),data)})
     }

     {
     lapply(x,function(data){data$fitted<-fitted(data)})
     }
     }
```

This isn't working however. I get 'null' as output once this is run

```
runit(listcontainingdataframes)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#No need for two `lapply`
x<-list(mtcars,iris)
lapply(x,function(data){
                  data$result<-lm(reformulate(termlabels=".",response=names(data)[1]),data)$fitted
   return(data)
         }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't work unfortunately. I get an error "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "result", value = c(-4.29725218642032,  : 
  replacement has 29 rows, data has 53 "

Comment: I have now tested the code for the sample data. It works. May be there is a problem with your data frame.

Comment: Yes, I'm checking there is one dataframe for which this error is coming through. I'm trying to figure out why

Comment: I see the fitted values being generated are 29 in number while the original dataset has 53 of which many are NAs thats why the error

Comment: In that case, you may want to remove the NA's before running the reg.

Comment: @oivemaria- try setting `na.action = na.exclude` in `lm()`.  What is the result of `getOption("na.action")`?

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
hellow<-lapply(x,function(data){
    data$result<-fitted(lm(reformulate
 (termlabels=".",response=names(data)[1]),data,na.action="na.exclude"))
 return(data)   
}
)
```

But, now when I use

```
list2env(hellow,.GlobalEnv)
```

to convert the list 'hellow' to individual dataframes, i get

```
    Error in list2env(hellow, .GlobalEnv) : 
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x
```

I understand the list hellow doesn't have any names, hence the error. But how could I get past it without assigning names to each of the elements in the list.

Thanks Metrics and Richard

Comment: It is easy to assign names using `setNames(hellow, paste0('dat', seq_along(hellow))`

Comment: well, the list "x" contains the dataframes, would ideally like it to automatically just retain the names of the dataframes contained in x, but even x after it was created didn't seem to retain any names. I tried names(x) and it shows up NULL just like names(hellow) does

Comment: If you already created data.frame objects it must be there in `ls(pattern='...)`

Comment: sorry, could you clarify the last bit

Comment: You said the list `x` contains dataframes.  Did you read it directly from the file to a list, i.e. `lapply(list.files(), function(x) read.csv(x, header=TRUE))` or created the objects one by one in the global environment.

Comment: If the objects are already created, check `ls()` .  If there is any pattern , say `dat1`, `dat2`, `dat3`, etc you can specify `ls(pattern='dat\\d+')` and it will give the vector of those object names.   Then use `setNames` based on that.  i.e. `setNames(hello, paste0(ls(pattern='dat\\d+'), 'somethingelse'))` if you need to have a modified object names

Comment: I'm trying to break the list down into individual dataframes since I ultimately wish to create a plot of fitted and actual values using ggplot2. Is there a way to by pass creation of dataframes to achieve that. Keeping in mind that there are about 10 dataframes in the list and I want to create plot for all of them

Comment: You may have to check `unnest` from `library(tidyr)` to create a single data.frame with groups to identify the list elements (assuming that the column names are identical across the list elements) and then try ggplot.

Comment: no, the columns aren't all with same names unfortunately. somedata frames might have the same column names

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it is not easier to comment.  Please do post as a separate question with a reproducible example and expected output

Comment: I ended up giving the list names and then unlisting the dataframes for the sake of convenience